# browser does not show out.println in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I've done the import

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
```

then I tried

```
out.println( "test");
```

but all what it does is the same to

```
System.out.println("test");
```

Both shows in log but not browser

Comment: no in a function in java class that is called by servlet

Comment: Us PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); in doGet, doPost or processRequest methods overriding the ones from Servlet class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you are in the servlet you must write:

```
response.getWriter().println("test");
```

Where `response` is of [`ServletResponse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html) type (or [`HttpServletResponse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) inheriting from it). If you are trying to call this from a different class, you must either pass the whole `ServletResponse` or `PrinterWriter` returned from `getWriter()` and use it as you `out` variable.

Note that:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
out.println( "test");
```

is equivalent to:

```
System.out.println("test");
```

Comment: its a little bit twisted in java =/
so now I have to send response to every function to get the writer functionality

this.validateName(request.getParameter("name"),response)

Comment: @Lamis: yes, assuming you need to write to response in `validateName()` method (very coutnerintuitive (?))

Comment: Yes thanks Tomasz, I'm trying to do ajax validation so I need to write down result...a little bit new to java so I hope I'm not messing things up :)

Comment: @Lamis: your `validateName()` should return `true`/`false` result which you should later interpret and send proper response. This is a bad, poorly testable design. That's it :-)

Comment: Thanks @Tomasz Nurkiewicz, will keep that in mind...I'm a php programmer so java still is a big shock especially when I have to do an hour work to figure out how to do "switch" for a string

Comment: @Lamis - "Do the tutorial Luke".

Answer (score 2):

What you did was simply a [static import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html), which allows you to use `System.out` without typing `System.`

If you want to write to the browser, you need access to the HttpServletResponse's writer:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
// you may pass out to your other classes, so that they write to the browser using
out.println("hello from a class");
```